# prove $\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sqrt{\left | xy \right |}}{z}$ doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, solution-verification

$z \in \mathbb{C}$ I want to show that the  $\lim_{z\to0}  \frac{\sqrt{\left | xy \right |}}{z}$ doesn't exist

so I take a sequence $z_n\rightarrow 0$ and a $w_n \rightarrow 0$ to prove it

let $z_n= \frac{1}{n}+i\frac{1}{n}$ the absolute value doesn't affect so  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{1/n^2}}{z_n}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{n}+i\frac{1}{n}\right)n}=\frac{1}{1+i} $

But if $w_n=\frac{1}{n}-i\frac{1}{n}$ then the  $\lim_{n\to\infty} w_n=\frac{1}{1-i} $
and therefore the limit does not exist.

I am new to complex analysis is this correct ?

Comment: You should have stated that $x=\operatorname{Re}z$ and that $y=\operatorname{Im}z$, but, yes, it is correct

Comment: Similarly to limits in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if we approach a point from different directions and the limits are different the overall limit does not exist.